# Is there any evidence that the Enterprise-E from the Star Trek:TNG films is a descendant of the Vengeance featured in Star Trek Into Darkness?

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, uss-enterprise, space-combat

Both ships are heavily armed and designed exclusively for combat, and both are technologically advanced for their respective eras,and I could easily see the Vengeance take on a Borg cube.

Comment: I don't see how the Enterprise-E could possibly be a descendant of the Vengeance, since the Vengance never existed in the timeline the TNG films were set in. The Enterprise-E is more likely to be a descendant of ships like Voyager and the Defiant, if anything (it had an EMH, for example).

Comment: The Vengeance is certainly a lot *larger* than other ships in its class, but it would be utterly outmatched by a Borg cube or a more modern ship like the Enterprise-D or E.

Comment: Is the Enterprise-E ever stated to be designed primarily for combat? It seems to have the same basic layout as the -D, and I'd expect it to have a similar multifunction role.

Comment: @Cadence: I suspect that is an idea that arises from video games that more or less aimlessly try to map the multi-purpose ships of a fleet whose tasks focus on exploration, diplomacy, and police seen on screen to the traditional combat-related roles of military strategy games. The fact that we only see Sovereign class ships in a total of three movies at all (in fact, only one of them), and that the TNG movies tend to be more action-oriented than Trek on TV, doesn't really help in getting a balanced impression of what Sovereign class starships do all day long, either.

Answer (score 6):

When the newer Star Trek movies were produced, the creatives behind the production decided that they would create a new universe/timeline. This was so that they could create a new origin and ongoing story while incorporating the familiar characters from The Original Series and earlier films, without having to worry about reconciling with canon from the almost 30 seasons of TV and 10 motion pictures that had been produced already.

So, the Vengeance was built by a Starfleet that had developed in a timeline that had been created by a time-travelling Romulan mining ship that first destroyed the USS Kelvin and then Vulcan a couple of decades later. This is the so-called Kelvin Timeline.

Whereas, the Enterprise-E was built in the origin timeline where the Kelvin and Vulcan had not been destroyed early in Starfleet/Federation history.

This means there is no reason that there would be any lineage or development from the Vengeance to the Enterprise-E, since the Vengeance hadn't been built from the point of view of the designers of the Sovereign class.

---

*As an aside, the Enterprise-E does not seem to have been built exclusively for combat - indeed, we see the ship engaged in the same general activities of exploration and diplomacy as we see the Enterprise-D before it. The Sovereign class may be better armed and shielded/armoured than the earlier Galaxy-class, but it was developed during and after the Borg incursions and Dominion War, so the weapons and defence technology would understandably be a considerable upgrade from the earlier ships.*